# Three RecyclerViews in one activity

Tags: android-studio, memory, android-recyclerview

I need to have three rows of pictures, one under the other. Each `RecyclerView`, which are scrollable, sit independently in each row. I came up with the idea to put three `RecyclerView`s, one under the other, and three adapters for the `RecyclerView`s and it looks very good. The only issue I have is it seems to consume a lot of memory and the scrolling is slow. I think the code is alright and the `RecyclerView`s are working alright, too, but maybe I am missing something or doing something wrong. Here is my activity that sets the adapters:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-XXXXX");
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.articles);
    RecyclerView recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.articles2);
    RecyclerView recyclerView3 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.articles3);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView3.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
   recyclerView3.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

    ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        articles.add(new Article());

    ArrayList<Article2> articles2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        articles2.add(new Article2());

    ArrayList<Article3> articles3 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        articles3.add(new Article3());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(articles, recyclerView));
    recyclerView2.setAdapter(new MyAdapter2(articles2, recyclerView2));
    recyclerView3.setAdapter(new MyAdapter3(articles3, recyclerView3));
}
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve the memory drain issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to increase your applications's memory, allowing it to store more in the heap. Your application could be running slow because of the images and the fact that it needs to set three different adapters to three different `RecyclerView`s that contain images. Usually, setting an image can be resource intensive, considering you have three rows of them. You can try to use less images but that might ruin the entire purpose of your application. I would recommend looking at [managing your application's memory](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) and looking at where you could optimise it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for advice. I will have rather big amount of pictures, arround 30 in each row - they are not big but will sum up. I also wonder is there any other or better way to achieve three independent scrolling views in one activity and layout?

Comment: There probably isn't a better way as such. It really depends on what you're rendering within those scrollable views. If you had only `TextView`s within your three adapters, your app would run faster. It really depends on what items you're trying to display. Keep in mind that you're trying to target the greatest number of devices out there, so if your app is running slow on a new phone, it's guaranteed to run slower on an older phone, too.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I do display pictures, not big but it will sum up because of its quantity. Thank you for your advices and yor time

Comment: You're very welcome Pawel. If you believe this answer has helped you, it would be great if you could accept it. Thankyou.